# Lilac disease/fungus diagnosis

Tags: identification, diagnosis, diseases, fungus, lilac

I have 5 Syringa meyeri cvs all with leaves curling upwards, in on themselves also. yellow with brown/black edges and spots on the leaves.  Is this just drought stress or something more serious.  If it is a fungal diseease any help identifying it much appreciated also remedies if any.[image: lilac]

Comment: Where in the world do you live?

Comment: Chieveley Near Newbury uk. It is a walled garden and they have thrived for at least 10 years

Comment: Amy, are we having an account mixup here? Or do you happen to  know the other user? See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how you can fix this. I am not including this in the question because it’s from different accounts and I can’t verify the correctness. This post will however be removed soon as it’s not an answer.